# ios Tab Bar Controller animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiviewanimation

I'm using a `Tab Bar Controller` and a pod `UICircularProgressRing` to animate a timer, when I'm switching to first controller from Timer Controller and right back, animation in Timer Controller is instantly set to end. Is possible to run in background animation so when i switch back animation continue running like you just hide and unhide view ?

Here is a gif with issue.

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/l0Iy1uwuTHHabVQGs)

**Edit 1**

Here's a example how I want to get working https://giphy.com/gifs/ios-animation-timer-3ohzdGYkzbc1gjnUPe

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Here is just one line of code to start ring animation `ring.setProgress(value: CGFloat(10), animationDuration: TimeInterval(10))`

Comment: Where you add this line?

Comment: In viewDidAppear in TimerController.  Link to project https://github.com/cpd/lib

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
import UIKit
import UICircularProgressRing

class TimerCountdownViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ring: UICircularProgressRingView!

    var currentValue: CGFloat?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        ring.setProgress(value: currentValue ?? 0, animationDuration: 0.0) { [weak self] in
            self?.ring.setProgress(value: 10.0, animationDuration: 8.0)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        currentValue = ring.currentValue
    }
}
```

I discovered that every time vc will disappear `UICircularProgressRing` pod marks `ring` as completed. The trick is I save `currentValue` every time I leave vc. After come back to vc I set progress of ring to old value and after that I continue progress to maxValue.

You could work on `animationDuration` when currentValue is coming to maxValue to make animation more smoothly.

Comment: I set maxValue to 10 from storyboard where you can set some ring options.

Comment: so if `maxValue = 10` and you use `setProgress(value: CGFloat(10)...` why you are surprised that circle is completed? what do you want achieve? Could you better explain what is your goal in your question? :)

Comment: Starting value is 0, I set maxValue to 10 and setProgress to 10, with duration 10 which mean that ring will going from 0 to 10 in 10 seconds, if maxValue was 100, value 10 and duration 10 then circle animation was like 10% from all circle in 10 seconds. There is not about maxValue, look on gif in first post

Comment: `currentValue` is get-only property.. Here is another gif how It should working when I switch between controllers but there I just hide and unhide views https://giphy.com/gifs/ios-animation-timer-3ohzdGYkzbc1gjnUPe

Also look again at gif in first post to see how animation is instantly set to end ( to maxValue) when i switch tabs.

Comment: Try Edit 3. Also please share `TimerController` whole implementation.

Comment: I want to see how you store `ring` property and etc.

Comment: I updated project by adding 2 buttons, on first press it create an instance of Timer Controller and add it as a childController, in next times it just unhide the view, (not remove) which gives the effect i want to achieve with tab bar buttons. Here is link on project https://github.com/cpd/lib

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes, I will try achieve this.